Rational solutions to polynomials and rational points
I have an old question confusing myself. Let $X$ be an algebraic variety defined over a finite extension $K$ of $\mathbb{Q}$ of degree $>1$ having a $K$-rational point $x$. Assume that there is no proper subfield $L$ of $K$ so that $X$ admits an $L$-model. Under this assumption it would not make sense, for example, $\mathbb{Q}$-points of $X$.
But the ''coordinates'' of $x$ might be contained in a proper subfield $L$, i.e., one might regard $x$ to be ''$L$-rational'' in some sense. Here is a concrete example: let $X=\mathrm{Spec}\left(\mathbb{Q}(i)[U,V,W]/(U+iV-\tfrac{i}{2}W)\right)$ over $K=\mathbb{Q}(i)$. Then $x=(0,\tfrac{1}{2},1)$ is a $\mathbb{Q}(i)$-rational point whose coordinates $0,\tfrac{1}{2},1$ are contained in $\mathbb{Q}$.
A rephrasing: let $f$ be an (irreducible) polynomial over $K$ which never be defined over any subfield. It might be not so weird to ask about $\mathbb{Q}$-solutions to the equation $f=0$. But it does not make any sense to asking $\mathbb{Q}$-rational points of the variety defined by $f$.
The question arouse from the following case. Let $\varphi:X\to Y$ be a morphism of algebraic varieties over $K$ (as above). Assume $Y$ has a (good) $\mathbb{Q}$-model, so it makes sense to speak about $\mathbb{Q}$-points of $Y$, but $X$ does not.

A vague (possibly absurd) assumption: suppose that $\varphi$ can be written explicitly and every ''coefficient'' appearing in this explicit expression is in $\mathbb{Q}$.

If this vague assumption makes in any sense, then the triple $(X,Y,\varphi)$ has no $\mathbb{Q}$-model since $X$ does not have such. Assume $X$ has a $K$-rational point $x$ whose coordinates are in $\mathbb{Q}$ (as above). Then, as the explicit expression of $\varphi$ accounts only rational numbers, i.e. $\mathbb{Q}$, $x$ maps down to a $\mathbb{Q}$-point of $Y$.
If one can make all these plausible, taking a strategy for showing $Y(\mathbb{Q})=\emptyset$ via $X(K)=\emptyset$ would fail.
It would be helpful if anyone points out the point I am confusing.

There is no question mark anywhere in your question so I'm not sure exactly what you're asking, but here is some discussion. Of course the issue is that the condition "all the coordinates lie in $\mathbb{Q}$" is not invariant under change of coordinates / isomorphism of varieties over $K$. So one has to specify the coordinates themselves as extra data.
In your example, taking $K = \mathbb{Q}(i)$, $X$ is described as Spec of a quotient of $K[U, V, W]$, meaning it implicitly comes with an embedding
$$i_X : X \hookrightarrow \mathbb{A}^3_K$$
which you have not made explicit. $\mathbb{A}^3_K$ has a canonical $\mathbb{Q}$-model, namely $\mathbb{A}^3_{\mathbb{Q}}$, so given a $K$-rational point $x \in X$ it now makes sense to take its image $i_X(x) \in \mathbb{A}^3_K$ and ask whether this image (not the original point) comes from a $\mathbb{Q}$-rational point on $\mathbb{A}^3_{\mathbb{Q}}$; more precisely we have a morphism $x : \text{Spec } K \to X$, we compose it with $i_X$ to get a morphism $i_X(x) : \text{Spec } K \to \mathbb{A}^3_K$, and it now makes sense to ask whether this morphism arises as the base change of some morphism $\text{Spec } \mathbb{Q} \to \mathbb{A}^3_{\mathbb{Q}}$. Of course this will depend on the choice of $i_X$ in general.
You can make sense of your condition on $\varphi : X \to Y$ in the same way. Writing $\varphi$ down explicitly requires choosing coordinates on both $X$ and $Y$, so now there are two embeddings $i_X : X \hookrightarrow \mathbb{A}^n_K, i_Y : Y \hookrightarrow \mathbb{A}^m_K$ and a commutative diagram involving the explicit form of $\varphi$, which is a different morphism
$$\varphi' : \mathbb{A}^n_K \to \mathbb{A}^m_K$$
and then as above it makes sense to ask whether $\varphi'$ (not $\varphi$) is the base change of a morphism $\mathbb{A}^n_{\mathbb{Q}} \to \mathbb{A}^m_{\mathbb{Q}}$.
